# CKEDITOR set focus after set data

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to update data in CKEditor as I type. However, when I set some text using `setData` the control loses focus. Even if I try to set focus using `editor.focus()` it doesn't work. Below is my code

```
editor.on('key', function(e) {       
 editor.setData('test', function() {
   editor.focus(); //Doesn't work
 }
}
```

I am not sure, what am I doing wrong in this case. I am using Firefox as my browser.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what exactly are you trying to do? In the example above you are attaching a key listener which gets executed with every single key press and you set the editor data to some random text what in practice doesn't allow typing and breaks the cursor position.

Comment: From what I have checked your code sample (although it had missing brackets) works perfectly fine in default CKEditor 4.9.1 full package however the use case itself makes no sense to me.